# Select a random line from listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selectedindex

With this program I am trying to make it so it generates information between two set values, while it does this part correctly I am also trying to get it so it generates a random number from this list (which it does in the loop) but then as a third function is to have the random number that was generated to also be selected in the listbox. I keep trying different forms of coding to get it to select the same number as the random one generated but I cant seem to get this to work.

```
Private Sub Generate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Generate.Click

    'Displays to enter correct information if lower is <=
    If System.Convert.ToInt32(Upper.Text) <= System.Convert.ToInt32(Lower.Text) Then
        List.Items.Clear()
        Number.Text = ""
        List.Items.Add("Please enter correct info Upper # higher value than Lower #")
    Else

        'If Upper range is higher than lower range then display numbers until total value is displayed
        List.Items.Clear()
        Number.Text = ""
        Dim i As Integer = Lower.Text

        Do While i <= Upper.Text 'Loop generates the numbers between values specified
            List.Items.Add(i)
            i += 1
        Loop

        'Select a random value from the list generated
        Dim myRandom As New Random
        Dim b As Integer = List.Items.Count
        Dim chosenItem As System.Object = List.Items.Item(myRandom.Next(b))
        Number.Text = chosenItem.ToString


    End If
```

Comment: `I cant seem to get this to work` is not very specific; this also appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23444010/1070452 with some changes from other help. that said, you should set `Option Strict On` to start

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the random number to "Number" but not to "List".

I'll add that the random number is not being generated in the loop as you state. The loop is there to add all of the numbers from the minimum number to the maximum number to "List". It is doing no more than that. The random number is generated in the code beneath the loop.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Generate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Generate.Click

Dim iMinimum As Integer = Integer.Parse(Lower.Text) 
Dim iMaximum As Integer = Integer.Parse(Upper.Text) 

List.Items.Clear()
Number.Text = ""

'Displays to enter correct information if lower is <=
If iMaximum <= iMinimum Then

    List.Items.Add("Please enter correct info Upper # higher value than Lower #")

Else

    'If Upper range is higher than lower range then display numbers until total value is displayed
    Dim i As Integer = iMinimum

    Do While i <= iMaximum 'Loop generates the numbers between values specified
        List.Items.Add(i.ToString)
        i += 1
    Loop

    'Select a random value and display
    Dim myRandom As New Random
    Dim iRandomNumber As Integer = myRandom.Next(iMinimum, iMaximum).ToString
    Number.Text = iRandomNumber.ToString
    List.Text = iRandomNumber.ToString

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your code is mostly correct.  To get the listbox to highlight the random number set the `.SelectedItem` property.

```
Private Sub Generate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Generate.Click
    Dim i As Integer = System.Convert.ToInt32(Lower.Text)
    Dim limit As Integer = System.Convert.ToInt32(Upper.Text)
    If limit <= i Then
        List.Items.Clear()
        Number.Text = ""
        List.Items.Add("Please enter correct info Upper # higher value than Lower #")
    Else

        'If Upper range is higher than lower range then display numbers until total value is displayed
        List.Items.Clear()
        Number.Text = ""


        Do While i <= limit 'Loop generates the numbers between values specified
            List.Items.Add(i)
            i += 1
        Loop

        'Select a random value from the list generated
        Dim myRandom As New Random
        Dim b As Integer = List.Items.Count
        List.SelectedItem = List.Items.Item(myRandom.Next(b))
        Number.Text = List.SelectedItem.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

On a side note, changing the variables to Double, instead of Integer, would allow you to use NumericUpDown controls instead of textboxes.  Just assign the `.Value` property without needing to convert anything.